# Is there a faster alternative to Auth0 API for requesting a user's profile using an Access Token?

Tags: auth0, sveltekit

I'm building my authentication manually using Auth0 API's since there is no SDK for SvelteKit at the time I'm writing this question.

So far I managed to get an Access Token, send it in a cookie to the browser and send it back at every request for a check using the Auth0 API for user profiles before passing the request to an endpoint.

The problem is the lack of speed. It takes about 1s to navigate from one page to another in the browser.

I don't think I can keep Access Tokens in memory server-side (due to the nature of SvelteKit) but I want to keep things simple.

Is there an alternative to Auth0 with a faster API?

Comment: You need to use [Redis](https://redis.io/) or similar in-memory database as a cache.

Comment: I will give Redis a try. [Clerk](https://clerk.dev/features/session-management) might work if I could understand how to use their API's.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Perhaps you would like to answer the question with an example? Can I use the accessToken as a key, email address as the value with a suitable expiration time?

Comment: Answering the question would take too much of my time and it is not an interesting problem.

Comment: :-) thanks anyway!